# Why is my querySelectorAll list length undefined?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I need a class to be dynamically added using JS in a Wordpress blog template. I manage to select all the relevant classes but I get "undefined".

I select all the ".layout-simple" classes that are present in the first 8 blog posts. My goal is to add a unique class next to the layout-simple class in sequential order, like so:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 layout-simple 1"></div>
<div class="col-lg-4 layout-simple 2"></div>
<div class="col-lg-4 layout-simple 3"></div>
<div class="col-lg-4 layout-simple 4"></div>
```

Here's what I'm currently using, logging "indexes.length" to the console outside the loop outputs the correct value. However, this is not the case inside the loop and I get undefined:

```
const indexes = document.querySelectorAll(".layout-simple");
console.log(indexes.length); // 8
indexes.forEach(function(indexes) {
  indexes.classList.add(indexes.length);
  console.log(indexes.length); // undefined
});
```

Comment: What effect are you trying to achieve, maybe there's a simpler way to do this using CSS only?

Comment: I'd like to add CSS grid properties to the columns, when each one has specific properties ( ex. grid-row-start: 6;  grid-row-end: 11) I have full control on where and how the columns are positioned. I originally created the blog in Hubspot but it was recently migrated to WP.  Hubspot uses HUBL which allowed me to use a loop.index that basically did what I now need.

Comment: @isherwood I believe we mitigated that problem with Nathaniel Flick 's solution by using the load function. Running it on a Wordpress template, Nginx, using a plugin to insert custom JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gotten this code to work, it's not super pretty but I did several things:

1. Add the window load function so your html is present before the js runs, then no undefined
2. Add a counter "x" that increments on each forEach, then add that as a class, though I don't recommend using integers for class names if you can help it - I added "grid" before the number and that works, the integer class does not
3. Use the classList and add functions to add the new class without erasing the existing ones

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
  const indexes = document.querySelectorAll(".layout-simple");
  console.log(indexes.length); // 8

  var x = 1;
  indexes.forEach(e => {
    e.classList.add('grid' + x++);
  })
});
```

```css
.layout-simple.grid1 {
  color: red;
}

.layout-simple.grid2 {
  color: blue;
}

.layout-simple.grid3 {
  color: green;
}

.layout-simple.grid4 {
  color: orange;
}

.layout-simple.grid5 {
  color: red;
}

.layout-simple.grid6 {
  color: blue;
}

.layout-simple.grid7 {
  color: green;
}

.layout-simple.grid8 {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 layout-simple">thing</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 layout-simple">thing</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 layout-simple">thing</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 layout-simple">thing</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 layout-simple">thing</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 layout-simple">thing</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 layout-simple">thing</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 layout-simple">thing</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, I'll leave the classes as grid1, grid2 etc, per your recommendation. The detailed explanation you provided was the cherry on the top. Thank you Nathaniel

Comment: @RodSanchez my pleasure! glad to be of help.